# Compute Quantile Function that uses an Indicator function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have to calculate the Quantile Function,
$$
F^{-1}_{L}(1-0.05),  
$$
where the distribution is given by $L=-(1-\textbf{1})$. Here $\textbf{1}$ is the indicator function with $P(\textbf{1}=1)=0.02$. Thus, inserting this we get,
$$
F^{-1}_{L}(1-0.05)=F^{-1}_{-(1-\textbf{1})}(0.95) = F^{-1}_{(\textbf{1}-1)}(0.95).
$$
Using the fact that $F^{-1}_{g(X)}(p)=g(F^{-1}_{X}(p))$ should yield that $F^{-1}_{(\textbf{1}-1)}(0.95)=F^{-1}_{\textbf{1}}(0.95)-1.$
Because the distribution function $F_{\textbf{1}}(1)=P(\textbf{1}\leq1)=1$, due to the indicator function only taking values $1$ or $0$, we get $F^{-1}_{\textbf{1}}(0.95)=1$. Thus, 
$$
F^{-1}_{L}(1-0.05)=F^{-1}_{\textbf{1}}(0.95)-1=1-1=0.
$$
However, the short solution that I have says that $F^{-1}_{L}(1-0.05)=-1$. Could someone please show me how they arrived to that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this $1$ just the constant number 1? Thus your random variable takes on the value $0$ with probability $0.02$ and $-1$ with probability $0.98$?

Comment: Are you talking about the "other" 1? In that case yes, it's just the constant number 1, i.e. $(1-\textbf{1})$ is "1 minus Indicator function". But how would this make the Quantile Function = -1?

Comment: Because your random variable takes on the value $0$ with probability $0.02$ and $-1$ with probability $0.98$. The quantile function evaluated at some $p$ gives you back the smallest value $x$ with $P(X \leq x) \geq p$. To put it another way, your whole computation was correct until you wrote $F_{\mathbf{1}}^{-1}(0.95)=1$, that's actually zero.

Comment: Ah! Thank you @Ian! Would you want to give this as an answer? If so I would be more than happy to mark this question as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your steps were correct all the way up until $F_{\mathbf{1}}^{-1}(0.95)=1$. This is actually $0$, since $P(\mathbf{1} \leq 0) = 0.98 \geq 0.95$, while $P(\mathbf{1} \leq a)=0$ for all $a<0$. Making this change gives the expected result.